# How to access property value in js?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
   let rates = {AUD: 1.5016, BGN: 1.9558, BRL: 3.741, CAD: 1.497, CHF: 1.1446}
```

How can I access each property? for example I tried :

```
let val ='EUR';
let test = rates[val];
```

Resulting in test = undefined?

Comment: `EUR` is not available in rates object.

Comment: You don't have a value "EUR" in the data that you showed in your example?

Comment: `EUR`is not in your sample set.  Is this the case for your code, or is that a sample set up issue?

Comment: What did you *expect* `test` to be?  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of how to access each value in the object. It will report the key and value to console.log.
The example generates an array of the  keys that do exist in the object, and then uses a `forEach()` method to just report the keys and values.  If you have a separate list of keys that you are using, you can use the `.hasOwnProperty()` method to test that a key exists in the object before you try to access it.

```js
let rates = {AUD: 1.5016, BGN: 1.9558, BRL: 3.741, CAD: 1.497, CHF: 1.1446}
// How can I access each property? for example I tried :

let keys = Object.keys(rates);

keys.forEach( key => console.log(`key = ${key}, value = ${rates[key]}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you attempted to do was find the EUR property/value, which is undefined in your object. What you CAN do, if you want to create another property (if I'm understanding you correctly) is

`rates.EUR = // whatever you want the rate to be`

If that's not what you're trying to do, provide more information as to what you need done.

Answer (score 0):

This may help for You:

```
     let rates = {AUD: 1.5016, BGN: 1.9558, BRL: 3.741, CAD: 1.497, CHF: 1.1446}
    You can access in two ways:
     1.  rates.AUD --Result is=1.5016
     2. rates['AUD'] -- Result is=1.5016

in case of you, it was showing undefined because of there is no property('EUR') exist in the above object (rated).
```